# Cancel and restart a certain Routine (python-script)

Tags: command-line, bash, python, cron

I have a question regarding a programm I run. Every once in a while, I need to restart a certain program.

For that case, I usually run:

`screen ./run.sh arg1 arg2 "arg3"`
(screen, since I don't know if there is another way of putting something in the background - but that's another thing.)

So, I think I could add a cronjob which (via `crontab -e`) which runs this program (do I need a bash-script for that though?) - But I don't know how to stop the process. Right now I'm cancelling it via <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> after I re-attached the detached session.

I was thinking of `kill`ing it, but I don't know the process-id when I start program. Can someone help me with that? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

tl;dr

start the process

wait 6 mins

stop the process,

(re)start the process (...)

Thanks

Comment: I can help with one part, at least: the **&** sign will run a command or script in the background, such as `conky &`. You can also `killall` by the name of the process rather than the PID, but I don't know if that's the best solution. Just a bit of input, will look more into it. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not opposing `bash` solutions, here's a script that does what you outlined. It can be added to `/etc/rc.local` to run on every boot. Just call it like `bash /path/to/script &` from within `/etc/rc.local`

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    screen ./run.sh arg1 arg2 "arg3" & # start in background
    CMDPID=$! # get pid of that command
    TIME=$( date +%s  ) # get timestamp

    # next while loop just keeps checking time
    # We don't want to block up CPU with 
    # continuous sleep command
    while [ $(date +%s) -lt $(($TIME+360)) ];
    do  
      sleep 0.25
    done
    kill -TERM $CMDPID # kill that process

    # return to the top and repeat the procedure    
done
```

Comment: Quesiton regarding this. Do I place this script in the rc.local? Like, If I understand you correctly, I can place this script (is it supposed to be "script.sh"?) in /home, and in my rc.local, I'll just type `bash /home/script.sh &` ?

Comment: @DasSaffe yes, exactly right. I may have not been clear in my phrasing. *Call* the script from `/etc/rc.local`  , don't replace it.   The `bash /home/script.sh &` is correct

Comment: One last question @Serg: in my `rc.local` I have the following line(s): `bash /home/script.sh`
exit 0 - Is that correct? Also, you mentioned it runs on every start now. For a (lets say 10 min intervall) I just add a cronjob then? For the cronjob I have this then? `*/10 * * * * bash /home/script.sh` - Or is it `*/10 * * * * ./home/script.sh`