# Restart a python script every hour or so

Tags: python, cron

So I have a python script that I launch in the terminal by just typing the script name (python SCRIPTNAME.py)

I'm just wondering is it possible to make a script or cron job that simply just stops then starts that python script every hour?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/800931/295286

Comment: What does your script do? It may be advantageous to have it sleep until the top of the hour and wake up, do it's few minutes of stuff then go back to sleep. Besides killing a job if it's in the middle of updating files can be risky.

Answer (score 5):

Best approach would be via GNU `timeout`  as in

```
timeout -k 3600 python3 /path/to/script.py
```

where -k stands for "kill after" and time in seconds.

So to have the script run, terminate and restart every hour, you could do

```
while timeout -k 3600 python3 /path/to/script; do
   sleep 2
done
```

where `sleep 2` is merely to add small delay before restarting

---

Alternatively consider using Threading module in Python to schedule the relevant parts of the script instead. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50537798/3701431

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to [daemonize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)), or create a service for, your Python script.  This is how other applications start up, and in the right order or at the right times.

You'll want to create a `systemd` service for your Python script, and then interface with it via `systemctl`.

```
systemctl restart mypython
systemctl enable mypython
```

Once you have your script working this way, you can set up `cron` to do whatever it is you need, which will probably be to restart the service.

Depending on the goal of your script, and your ability to determine if it is running properly, you could enhance your service to report if it stops running, or even look into solutions such as [`monit`](https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/).

---

As pointed out, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/800941/13247) provides useful information, but contains out-of-date tools, such as `rc.local`.  Instead of using `systemd`, you can track the PID of the process, and then kill that process and re-run your script every hour.